# Dzava Lighthouse index.js: not found using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, lighthouse

So i had this working at one point but it is now failing in my laravel app. So i have my call to the lighthouse audit in my app/Models/Account.php file

```
            (new Lighthouse())
                ->setOutput( $link )
                ->setTimeout( 180 )
                ->accessibility()
                ->bestPractices()
                ->performance()
                ->pwa()
                ->seo()
                ->setLighthousePath('./../../node_modules/lighthouse/lighthouse-cli/index.js')
                ->audit($this->url);
        $html = '
    <a href="/report.html" target="_blank">Click here to show the lighthouse report in a new tab</a>';
        } catch( AuditFailedException $e ) {
            logger( $e );
            $html = '
    <p>' . $e->getOutput() . '</p>';
        }
```

I get an error in my log `exec: ./node_modules/lighthouse/lighthouse-cli/index.js: not found` however i find I have no lighthouse-cli folder but do have a cli folder in lighthouse and in there is an index.js file. I have also tried `./../node_modules/lighthouse/lighthouse-cli/index.js`, `./../../node_modules/lighthouse/lighthouse-cli/index.js`, `exec: ./../../node_modules/lighthouse/cli/index.js: not found` and probably other varients but the report doesnt audit.

I have installed dzava/lighthouse with composer and yarn installed lighthouse (as per the docs - https://github.com/dzava/lighthouse-php) and confirm that the index.js file is in node_modules/lighthouse/cli/ what is causing this issue? what should be the correct path? why is it assuming the path is ./node_modules/lighthouse/lighthouse-cli/index.js despite there being no lighthouse-cli folder? Has anyone got this to work in laravel with dzava/lighthouse version 0.2.0?

Comment: `npm install` is all good?

Comment: do you know that lighthouse is now in v11 and this was tested on v8, a bit old..

Comment: i think the problem is form 'dzava/lighthouse-php' you can use [lighthouse](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse) directly, it`s better to use safe library in your code ;)

Comment: Actually went down route of using the spatie package which as with this worked great on my dev box but broke on production. I've decided that @HoseainSanadgol has a better method as suspect this is due to this being a server so needs to be headless. Indeed why use a wrapper for this